# Making looped HTTP requests

Tags: json, swift, http, concurrency, urlsession

I am writing a translator app that connects with an online translation API. Due to size limitations in the API, I have written my program to send text one sentence at a time, and then join the translations together. I have looped

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "translationQueue")
        
        for line in lines {
          serialQueue.async {
            print("line is: " + line)
            
            var jpText = String(line)
            
            if jpText.isEmpty {
              jpText = "\n"
            }
            
            let escapedStr = jpText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: (NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed))
            let urlStr:String = ("https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q="+escapedStr!+"&langpair="+langStr!)
            let url = URL(string: urlStr)
            
            // Creating Http Request
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
            
            
            // If empty, don't feed to translator.
            if escapedStr!.isEmpty {
              //translatedLines.append("\n")
              self.enTextView.text = translatedLines
            }
            
            else {
              let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
              configuration.waitsForConnectivity = true
              let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
              var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
              
              let group = DispatchGroup()
              group.enter()
              
              dataTask?.cancel()
              
              dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                  // self?.errorMessage += "DataTask error: " + error.localizedDescription + "\n"
                  print("DataTask error: " + error.localizedDescription + "\n")
                  
                } else if
                  let data = data,
                  let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  response.statusCode == 200 {
                  let jsonDict: NSDictionary!=((try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary)
                  
                  // if(jsonDict.value(forKey: "responseStatus") as! NSNumber == 200){
                  let responseData: NSDictionary = jsonDict.object(forKey: "responseData") as! NSDictionary
                  
                  group.leave()
                  
                  var translatedString = String()
                  translatedString = responseData.object(forKey: "translatedText") as! String
                  
                  let data = translatedString.data(using: .utf8)
                  
                  let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
                    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                  ]
                  
                  guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: .none) else {
                    return
                  }
                  
                  let decodedString = attributedString.string
                  print("decoded: " + decodedString)
                  
                  translatedLines.append(decodedString)
                  translatedLines.append("\n")
                  
                  
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.enTextView.text = translatedLines
                  }
                }
              }
              
              dataTask?.resume()
              group.wait()
            }
          }
        }
```

But the translation output comes out in a random order. I broadly understand that there are concurrent requests being sent. But what can I do in my for-loop to make sure the entire send/receive happens before moving to the next iteration?

Comment: Serialize asynchronicity. Simplest way is Dispatch Group plus wait plus notify. Personally I’d use Combine Framework but that’s harder.

Comment: Please elaborate in a response.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following technique:

1. Preallocate an array for translation results. A result may be either a success (with associated translated text) or a failure (with associated error type). Swift's `Result` type comes in very handy for this use case.
2. Assign each data task an index (essentially, an index in the array created on step 1).
3. Execute all data tasks simultaneously, coordinating them using a `DispatchGroup`.
4. When completed either with success or failure, each task writes its result to the array.
5. When all data tasks have been completed, the dispatch group will notify the main queue and execute our completing block where we can update the UI.

Here's a quick playground code loosely based on yours that uses the tecnhique I described above:

```swift
let lines = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

enum TranslationError: Error {
    case neverRequested
    case countNotBuildUrl
    case dataTaskError(localizedDescription: String)
    case responseDidNotContainData
    case parsingError
}

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var translationResults = [Result<String, TranslationError>](repeating: .failure(.neverRequested), count: lines.count)
for i in 0..<lines.count {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let line = lines[i]
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get")!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: line),
        URLQueryItem(name: "langpair", value: "en|fr")
    ]
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        translationResults[i] = .failure(.countNotBuildUrl)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
        continue
    }

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        print("Data task #\(i) finished.")
        defer {
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                translationResults[i] = .failure(.dataTaskError(localizedDescription: error.localizedDescription))
            }
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                translationResults[i] = .failure(.responseDidNotContainData)
            }
            return
        }
        guard let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary,
            let responseData = jsonDict.value(forKey: "responseData") as? NSDictionary,
            let translatedLine = responseData.value(forKey: "translatedText") as? String else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                translationResults[i] = .failure(.parsingError)
            }
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            translationResults[i] = .success(translatedLine)
        }
    }
    print("Starting data task #\(i)...")
    dataTask.resume()
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    // Handle errors and update the UI
    print(translationResults)
})
```

A few notes:

1. It's important that all data task completion blocks update the `translationResults` array on the same queue, that's why I'm calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` every time. Not doing it may result in weird crashes because arrays are not thread-safe in Swift.
2. This technique does not allow to incrementally update the UI line by line as the translations come in, but it's possible to add something like that.
3. In a real app I would refactor this code and split it into several methods with more focused responsibilities. However to make it easier to understand the idea I decided not to do it.
4. Error handling in my code is also very basic just to show the idea and keep it show, and it doesn't include some other checks I'd do in a real app.
5. I'm pretty sure there are better and more elegant ways to achieve the same result so I'm looking forward to see if someone comes up with a better implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I have updated my code and added a few lines of code for the DispatchQueue. Everything now works in order, but it's a bit slow as each translation is happening line by line. Is there a way to make it work through each iteration faster? I tried changing the .wait() to group.wait(timeout: .now() + 1) for 1 second, but then some translation lines get jumbled up again.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be slow if you have many lines of text because a DispatchGroup won't finish until the last data task is finished. If you're dealing with hundreds or thousands of lines, I'd suggest to group the lines into batches. Each batch will have its own dispatch group and will update the UI on completion, that way the user will see the translation coming up incrementally. Another thing you need to take care of is a proper error handling. If possible, I would use Combine or some other reactive framework (RxSwift or ReactiveSwift) for this task, it's a perfect use case for it.